# breaker box in old camper

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

I have an old tin can camper, we use an extension cord to plug it in to a 120V outlet for power.  We just realized that most of the wiring was just two wires with no ground (probably why it would pop breakers when we plugged it in).  Anyway, we want to put in a breaker box and 10/2 wiring.  We bought a 30A breaker box with two circuits but can't figure out how to wire it.  The wire that comes from the outside "plug" has three wires, black, white and ground...how do we connect that wire to the breaker box?  Our camper has three outlets...one runs a window a/c unit, one runs a mini fridge and sometimes a phone charger, the other usually charges our phones.  The outlet for the a/c unit is on it's own wire and could go directly into the breaker box.  the other two outlets are on the same wire and go into the breaker box.  Are we doing this all wrong?  Please help!

Comment: Does it plug into a regular outlet, or a fatter-than-usual outlet?

Comment: What brand and model is the new breaker box? You could instead add a photo of the label inside the door.

Comment: 10/2 wire is _way_ oversized for the (most likely) 15A or 20A circuits you'll be pulling inside the trailer. At today's prices for copper, skip that and go with 12/2 or 14/2 as appropriate.

Comment: Do not use domestic (solid single) wiring in a camper! It needs to be stranded cable, which is flexible enough for the movements it's going to get. Any earth will ideally need to be attached to an earth rod or the proper (blue in UK) plug/socket  on site.

Comment: I finally got in contact with an electrician that could help and he drew me pictures!  :)  Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a 30 amp 120v RV plug that is common in the US.

the black is hot White neutral and green ground.

As you only have 1 leg power the feeder black ties to both buss bars or black on both.

The white goes to the neutral buss this should be isolated from the ground/ box and the ground goes to the metal box

there is no 240 in this setup but this is how most 120v systems are setup and you can use the breakers as single pole no doubles.